# Print lines before or after keywords

Tags: macos, list, awk, grep

Absolute beginner here trying to figure this out. Fairly simple task but I could not find a proper solution. I've learned that grep is ideal for this, but this problem has just enough variables that my basic understanding can't figure it out.

I have a text file and want to print lines either before or after certain keywords.

Example:

Input

```
Alpha
textfoo
text
text
qux
Beta
text
Charlie
textbar
text
text
qux
Delta
text
text
Echo
textbaz
text
text
text
qux
Foxtrot
```

I want to print the lines **before** keywords 'foo' 'bar' and 'baz', and **after** keyword 'qux'. However the 'foo' 'bar' and 'baz' are attached to the text without a space like the example. The desired result in this order:

Output

```
Alpha
Beta
Charlie
Delta
Echo
Foxtrot
```

<strike>Running OSX so no GNU grep :(</strike> Just learned about brew and installed GNU grep :), so that's an option now. Thanks for the help! I'm really at a loss.

**Solution:**

```
awk 'n {print;n=0} /qux/ {n=1;next} /foo/ {print f} {f=$0} /bar/ {print g} {g=$0} /baz/ {print h} {h=$0}' file
```

Comment: You might want to check out the `-B` and `-A` options for `grep`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with `awk`

```
awk '/foo/ && !/foobar/ {print f} {f=$0} n {print;n=0} /foobar/ {n=1}' file
Alpha
Beta
Charlie
Delta
Echo
Foxtrot
```

It prints all words in line before line that contains `foo`, but not `foobar`
And prints all line after line with `foobar`

This may work too:

```
awk 'n {print;n=0} /foobar/ {n=1;next} /foo/ {print f} {f=$0}' file
Alpha
Beta
Charlie
Delta
Echo
Foxtrot
```

Comment: Thanks! But foo1 2 and 3 are actually different variables. I guess I should have reflected that. Edited variables for clarity.

I just adjusted what you gave me and it worked perfectly!

`awk 'n {print;n=0} /foobar/ {n=1;next} /foo1/ {print f} {f=$0} /foo2/ {print g} {g=$0} /foo3/ {print h} {h=$0}' file`

For some reason the first code just hung and didn't do anything.